# Is that posssible to filter api data before get from server?

Tags: angular, typescript

Im working with an api which has lots of data (more than 10k now and growing every day). Im getting all of them from server and then filtering with time (also im using pagination for render 10 data on every page). But i guess its not so good for performance. Is that possible to filter them before get all data? For example i want to get data which is uploaded in last 30 days and when user press the button get another 30 days.
Im not very well on speaking english so probably i made some mistakes. i hope you could understand and help me.

Comment: in Rest api you have to update rest api there are many ways.. try to learn graphql api ...!

Comment: The filtering must be made server side. So you need to: use other methods of the api or create new one to filter the data.

Comment: As a rule of thumb you should filter and possibly sort data as close to where the data resides as possible. If the data resides in a data base (like sql server) then you should filter the data at the database server level (in the retrieval query). Every step further away means the filter gets more expensive. The next end point in that progression would be filtering in memory in the Web end point. And the step further from what would be in the client layer in the browser. So modify your end point and sever code to accept a filter parameter(s) and filter as close to the data as possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you can modify the server's code, you could add some parameters to your entrypoint
(something like `url?limit=50` to limit to 50 entries)

If not, you're bound to filter what you get from your server.

Comment: I know this method, but I would like to hear other methods if exists. Thank you for your response

Answer (score 1):

You must have access to your server, add a "TAKE" clause on the list you are sending back to the client, where it tells the database to return the top 50 or so entries.

Plus, you can use HTTP_INTERCEPTOR as middleware to catch a request before it reaches the server, or catch the response before it reaches your "subscribe".

Read about the interceptor, it's a great and recommended way to handle http requests. Here you go [Angular Interceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor).

Also read about Angular Resolvers, you can use these to improve performance and load data before a component's lifecycle typescript part begins. Here you go
[Angular Resolver](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve).

Good Luck!